# How to copy value from one column to another column however be one row lower in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, finance

How would I have copy the last value from one column and copy this to another column in Pandas. I am coding a stock portfolio withdrawal strategy and I need to copy the `["Portfolio Remaining"] variable * ["Return"]` from index number `[1: End_date]` as after the first year the portfolio after the withdrawal `(["Portfolio Remaining"])` column needs to multiplied from index `[1: End_Date]`. So I want a column to copy another column however the value in the new column will be 1 row lower in the new column.

I have tried to use
`df(Equity_Value).loc[0] * (df["Return])` then use
`df3["Portfolio_Value"].loc[1:End_Date] * (df["Return"] + 1).cumprod()` however the calculations were wrong and python said this method isn't suitable due to the slicing however I am unsure how to do this in Pandas. I can't find anything on the documentation or online resources on how to do this.

Comment: Could you provide a small example? It's kinda hard to understand what you really need

Comment: if you can do your calculation fine, and all you need to do is shift you records by one row, try this:
`pd["new_column"] = pd["old_column"].shift(1)`

It helps people understand your question better if you post some data and clean your sample code a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `pd` is a pandas DataFrame, the following works for shifting records by one row:

`pd["new_column"] = pd["old_column"].shift(1)`

details at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html